# How to search Set using Jinq

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jinq

I have collection `Set<Tag>` in my entity class. `Tag` class contains only `Long id` and `String` value. Im trying to find `Place` by `Tag` but im getting error `Could not analyze lambda code`

```
    String name = places.getTag().getName();
    if (name != null) {
        stream = stream.where(p -> p.getTags().iterator().next().getName().equals(name));
    }
```

There is way to make it tight and elegant? 
I know that my code is incorrect, and im getting error because Jinq probably doesn't support something like this `p.getTags().iterator().next().getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with you schema, but maybe you could do a join to flatten your data structures with something like this:

```
stream
   .joinList( p -> p.getTags() )
   .where( pair -> pair.getTwo().getName().equals(name) );
```

Again, it depends on your database schema and entities, but if you have the right relationships setup, then you could go even simpler with something like this:

```
tagStream
   .where( tag -> tag.getName().equals(name) )  // get the right tag
   .selectAllList( tag -> tag.getPlaces() )     // get all places with that tag
```

If you can't use a join though, you can try using a subquery, but subqueries behave a bit finnicky on different JPA providers. For subqueries, just make sure the subquery is in the same format as a normal query.

```
stream = stream
   .where(p -> JinqStream.from(p.getTags())
      .where( tag -> tag.getName().equals(name) )
      .count() > 0);
```